# How to implement server side google authorization on dotnet core

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, .net-core, in-app-billing, google-api-dotnet-client

I need to implement server-side validation for in-app purchases of my android application, in C# dotnet core platform which runs on linux.

I have read [this page](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/authorization) so many times and finally found about [this issue](https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/933) which shows I'm not alone. It looks like Google currently does not directly support dotnet core fully.

Is there anyone who could achieve this using any third party library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you linked to is about *users* logging in via MVC.

If you want to use a service account:

- If your server is on Google Cloud (e.g. Compute Engine, Container Engine or App Engine) you shouldn't need to do anything
- Otherwise, download a service account JSON file by following [the instructions here](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started) and make sure the server has local access to the file then either:

  - Set the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable and use `GoogleCredential.GetApplicationDefault` or
  - Use the new `GoogleCredential.FromFile` method (introduced in 1.29.0 of the client library support package)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know .Net Core does not have an Oauth2 server implementation (yet?)...

There are few posibilities out there as commented [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/1557), but most used is Identity Server  (something that can be integrated in your custom ASP Net Core project and does the job)

> "IdentityServer4 is an OpenID Connect and OAuth 2.0 framework for
>   ASP.NET Core."

Main link: http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/index.html

Adding Support for External Authentication:
http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/quickstarts/4_external_authentication.html?highlight=google

Take a look at the Setup and OVerview part and You'll find that this would fit your needs (I'm pretty sure)

I hope it helps,

Juan

Comment: Maybe I could not explain well. I do not need to authenticate users. I need to authenticate my service account with google so I can call purchases.get with purchaseToken to verify if app users have purchased a product or not.

Comment: Have you found any way to do this?